# Where to find a dirty CSS to a parser?

Tags: css

I'm needing a very complex or dirty CSS to write a parser.
This CSS should use the most powerfull CSS rules, with several attributes and selectors, media-queries, comments, webkits selectors and so on.

Someone knows where I can find?

P.S. It's not needed the CSS to be readable or fit to any page. What I need is it should have a correct syntax.

Comment: Why don't you just using the one called Bootstrap?

Comment: Are you asking `"Where do I find a repository of awful CSS to test a CSS parser I'm writing?"`

Comment: While an "acid test" may eventually be useful, I would start with a series of simple tests, which each focus on one specific part of the spec.  YMMV

Comment: @HuyVo This could be a good start. But maybe not to a parser. To a parser doent matter if it fits to a good layout. So, maybe on boostrap I could jave a good material, but maybe I will not have enougth material to a parser.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a broad range of CSS test cases to try and break a CSS parser you're writing, the [official W3C CSS test suite](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/Overview.en.html) is a rather exhaustive resource.

If you'd like to clone the repository for the above tests, then you'll find it [here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-test).

## What do the browsers do?

Individual browser engines, like Gecko/ Chromium/ WebKit etc, test their CSS parsing (and rendering) using the W3C tests above. They do also have a variety of test cases in the various engine repositories although they're probably too fragmented to be useful. The [Gecko (Mozilla) set](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/reftests) is one example of those (specifically all the css- subdirectories in there).

Keep in mind though that these tests - while numerous - are written for user agents. If you're interested in just the CSS, you'll need to pop it out of those test cases.

There are also some older test suites still around such as the Mozilla [NGLayout CSS test cases](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/testcases/css/) which are useful for testing earlier aspects of the CSS specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PostCSS's Parser tests](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-parser-tests). They have generated a number of test cases, that they use to test their own parser. Their [Licence](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-parser-tests/blob/master/LICENSE) would allow you to take a copy of them and use them in any other project.

As the repo states (*emphasis added*):

> This project contains base tests for every [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) CSS parser, including:
>
> - 24 CSS files to test extreme cases of the CSS specification.
> - Integration tests by popular website styles to test CSS from the wild.
>
> **These tests are useful for any CSS parser**, not just parsers within the PostCSS ecosystem.

Comment: +1 but PostCSS parses http://browserhacks.com invalid syntaxes, isn't it? That's a must have feature of PostCSS but are all their tests valid CSS?

Comment: @FelipeAls, a very good point. Yes, some of the tests do include CSS that would not pass validation; i assumed when OP asked for "dirty CSS", this included styles that wouldnt pass validation, and that the idea of his parser was to strip out these invalid styles/infer correct styles from them

Comment: Yeah, there are "only valid selectors" and "invalid selectors that you still want to parse and output in real projects because some rendering engine thinks it's valid" approaches… _Webdev as usual_ :)